# AVL Tree Rebalancing in C++

Tags: c++, treenode, avl-tree

I'm working on an AVL tree. I think I've got all of the rotate functions working correctly. I have a rotateleft, rotateright, rotateleftright, and rotaterightleft function. They all take a node as a parameter.I don't know what node to pass to those parameters. Can you take a look at my AVL tree rebalance function and tell me if I have it correct, and what I need to pass to each of these functions. So far, I have the root or the top node, but i think I'm wrong. How do I tell what I need to pass to these functions?

Here is the function:

```
void BinaryTree::rebalance(Node *N)
{
    int count = 1;
    if((N->getLeft()->getHeight()) > (N->getRight()->getHeight() + 1))
    {
        if(N->getLeft()->getLeft()->getHeight() > N->getLeft()->getRight()->getHeight())
        {
             rotateRight(root);
             recalculate(root, count);

        }

        else
        {
             rotateLeftRight(root);
              recalculate(root, count);
        }
    }
    else if(N->getRight()->getHeight()> N->getLeft()->getHeight() + 1)
    {
        if(N->getRight()->getRight()->getHeight() > N->getRight()->getLeft()->getHeight())
        {
             rotateLeft(root);
              recalculate(root, count);
        }

        else
        {
            rotateRightLeft(root);
             recalculate(root, count);
        }
    }
}
```

here is my rotate leftright

```
Node* BinaryTree::rotateLeftRight(Node *N)
{
    Node *newNode =  new Node();//declares a new Node
    newNode = N->getLeft();//sets the node

    N->setLeft(rotateLeft(newNode->getLeft());//sets the left subtree
    recalculate(root);//recalculates the height
    root->setHeight(NULL);//sets the height of the root node
    return rotateRight(N);//retuns the tree rotated right
}
```

and here is my rotate left function.:

```
Node* BinaryTree::rotateLeft(Node *N)
{
    Node *newNode =  new Node();//declares a new node
    newNode = N->getRight();//sets the new node to the right child of N
    N->setRight(newNode->getLeft());//sets the right of N equal to new nodes left child
    newNode->setLeft(N);//sets the left child of the new node to N

    return newNode;//retuns the newNode
}
```

if i have the tree 50 20 10 and 15 what do i pass to the each of these functions to rebalance the tree?

Comment: This seems better suited to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If it is for something else but homework then don't bother. RB tree is more efficient.

Comment: it is for homeowrk, and im stuck

Comment: if your code is working, submit it to codereview. If it's not, then here is fine. Either way, you will have to provide more code for people to be able to grok it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code that you did not do in the one you submitted in another question, that is you don't check for nullary pointers in your code:

- you don't check if `N` is `NULL` at the begining of the method
- you don't check in the line below (and in its symmetrical sibling) if the left and right nodes are `NULL`

  ```
  if((N->getLeft()->getHeight()) > (N->getRight()->getHeight() + 1))
  ```

Regarding the algorithm itself, it depends on the behaviour of the rotation functions. The algorithm as described in the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avl_tree) explains that the second case in your nested if (the `rotateLeftRight` and `rotateRightLeft` methods) should perform 2 rotations. If your rotation functions are conform to that description, you should be alright.

The case of `recalculate` has been taken care of in an other question, but in this situation, you actually don't need to recalculate the height for the whole subtree, as you correctly told me in comments in that question. The only changing nodes are the ones whose children have been changed. You should perform that computation within each specific rotation method, since each case describe exactly which nodes get updated.

Comment: okay for this function in order to be called the difference in the heights heights has to be greater than one. and that line, i created a compute difference function that gets the height of the left subtree, and the right one, and then is finds the difference. that line now reads:if(getHeightDifference(N) > 1 )//if the left subtree is heigher than the right by more than 1

Comment: Ok, then test out your code, and add an update to your question if it still poses problems.

Comment: im trying to figure out what to pass to the rotateleftright function do i pass the root?

Comment: You need to revise the basics of pointer usage and memory allocation in C++. Please do that first.

Comment: Look at the first two lines of each rotation function, there's a mistake in there regarding pointer and memory allocation. Also, these functions both return a node, but your original rebalance function does not use them. You need to decide whether these functions work by side effect or by constructing new trees. Hopefully you'll figure it out.

Comment: so are you saying that i shouldnt declare a new node? i tried to just declare newnode equal to the left or right child, but it kept on throwing exceptions.

Comment: I am saying that these two instructions contradict each other, hence my advice for you to review pointers in C++. Please follow my advice and review your code afterward, it should be obvious. As for whether you need to allocate a new Node or not, here is my question: is there an extra node in the tree after a rotation, or does the number of nodes remain the same?

Comment: it should just stay the same i use the new node to rotate the tree.

Comment: you must understand that memory is **not** managed in C++: when you create a new instance, you must find a way to delete it when it is needed anymore. As I said, revise your knowledge of memory management and pointers in C++. Besides, even if you didn't need to care about deleting object by hand, do you really think that the 2 lines I pointed out achieve anything? Don't answer now, revise first please.

Comment: so i changed those lines to: Node *newNode = N->getLeft();//sets the node. is that what you meant and yes i do know about the delete[] syntax.